# PHP: How do you output just one line in an array and have it remember where it left off?

Tags: php, arrays, list

I have a list in an array and want to output just ONE row into the output.csv file.  I will run this script once per week and want to output the lines in order from top to bottom.  And then at the end (in this case, the 6th week), loop back to the beginning.  How can the script keep track of where it left off so it knows which line to process next?  Any help is appreciated!

```
$list = array
(
"some text|blue|22|sky",
"some text|red|42|ocean",
"some text|green|25|mountain",
"some text|orange|62|space",
"some text|brown|15|earth",
);

$file = fopen("output.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
{
fputcsv($file,explode('|',$line));
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Can you not use a persistent storage like memory or even database?

Comment: will the file be same as `output.csv` every week?

Comment: You can also save the next line number to a file or cookie and retrieve it on next run.

Comment: Is the size of the list unchanging?  If so, you can use PHP's date function to get the week number ($week = $date->format("W") if you have a date object) and perform a mod calculation.  Then there is no need to save state anywhere.  For instance, if it is the 7th week of the year the calculation would yield 7 % 6 = 1, meaning it would output the first line in the file (if yours are 0 indexed, as they likely are, you will need to subtract one though).

Comment: @saleh Yes, the CSV file name will stay the same and the contents will be replaced each week.

Comment: @karlo - that might be the easiest thing to do in this case... can you kindly point me to a simple example of this?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go with the file based approach to keep track of things.It will be more reliable and portable approach due to no dependence on timezones or DST

> **File based approach**

```
<?php

//read the last record
try
{
    $fileName = "record.txt";

    if ( !file_exists($fileName) ) {
        file_put_contents("record.txt",'0'); // default - first line if run first time
    }

    $fp = fopen($fileName, "r+");
    if ( !$fp ) {
        throw new Exception('File open failed.');
    }  

    $str = (int) fread($fp, 1); // read the first char, index to use for array
    fclose($fp);

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
} 


$list = array
(
    "some text|blue|22|sky",
    "some text|red|42|ocean",
    "some text|green|25|mountain",
    "some text|orange|62|space",
    "some text|brown|15|earth",
);

$file = fopen("output.csv","w");
$line = $list[$str];
fputcsv($file,explode('|',$line));
fclose($file);

//save what index should it read next time
$incr =  intval($str)+1;
$incr = $incr == ( count($list) )? 0: $incr;
file_put_contents("record.txt",$incr);
```

> **Date based approach**

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

$week = $date->format("W");


$list = array
(
    "some text|blue|22|sky",
    "some text|red|42|ocean",
    "some text|green|25|mountain",
    "some text|orange|62|space",
    "some text|brown|15|earth",
);


$str = $week % count($list);

$file = fopen("output.csv","w");
$line = $list[$str];
fputcsv($file,explode('|',$line));
fclose($file);
```

One advantage with Date based approach worth mentioning is if run the script multiple times in a given week you would get the same output but that's not the case with file based approach as the record.txt will change everytime the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution for what you described above would be:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    "some text|blue|22|sky",
    "some text|red|42|ocean",
    "some text|green|25|mountain",
    "some text|orange|62|space",
    "some text|brown|15|earth",
);
$filename = "output.csv";

// Getting last week line from csv file. And replacing ','s with '|'s
$last_week = str_replace(',', '|', str_replace( '"', '', trim( file_get_contents($filename) ) ) );

// Getting the array index of last week line
$last_week_index = array_search($last_week, $list);

// Checking either its first week or not, for this week index
if(is_null($last_week_index) || $last_week_index == (count($list)-1)) {
    $current_week_index = 0; // 0 in case of first week
} else {
    $current_week_index = $last_week_index + 1; // incrementing the index from last week for current week
}

// Preparing the line to write
$line_to_write = explode('|', $list[$current_week_index]);

// Closing file handler
$file = fopen($filename, "w");

// Writing to file
fputcsv($file, $line_to_write);

// Closing file handler
fclose($file);
```

Let me know in the comments if you have conflict understanding the logic.